# iOS 8 Form Sheet Modal Dialog Resizing After Display

Tags: objective-c, ios8, resize, modal-dialog

I work on an application where it shows a modal popup by performing a segue using the form sheet modal style and then a horizontal flip animation. In iOS 7 made the form take up the correct screen size by calling:

```
self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,300,300);
```

for example and this set the modal dialogs dimensions to the correct size. There is also a button in this modal dialog that allows the user to see 'more detail' and for this the view grows to show some additional content. We did this again by animating the view and make a call to set the bounds to something a little bigger on the superview.

For Example:

```
self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,600,600);
```

In iOS 7 this worked just great. In iOS 8 however it has stopped working. Instead of modifying the super view's bounds we now have to call:

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 300);
```

This resolves the forms appearance after opening but i can't find a way to manipulate the size of the view there after. Setting the super views bounds has no effect.

I can see in iOS8 Apple has made a change to form sheets to have a 3 view hierarchy (your view -> shadow view -> transition view -> window) where as before in iOS 7 it was just a 2 view hierarchy (your view -> shadow view -> window).

I've tried manipulating the super view's super view but that did not have the desired effect.

Is anyone else seeing this / found a way around it? Here is an example project:

https://github.com/ingybing/FormSheet

Run it in iOS 7 Simulator and you will see the desired behaviour. That is what I'm struggling to get working in iOS 8

View Controller Example:

```
#import "ModalWindowViewController.h"

@interface ModalWindowViewController ()
@property bool minimised;
@property bool isInitialViewLoadLayout;
@end

#define is_iOS8 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]floatValue] >= 8)

@implementation ModalWindowViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.minimised = YES;
    self.isInitialViewLoadLayout = YES;

    if(is_iOS8)
    {
        // Set initial size in iOS 8 etc.
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 300);
    }
}

- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    if (self.isInitialViewLoadLayout)
    {
        self.isInitialViewLoadLayout = NO;

        if(!is_iOS8)
        {
            // Set initial size in iOS 6,7 etc.
            self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)minMaxTouched:(id)sender
{
    CGRect newSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);

    if (self.minimised == YES)
    {
        newSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 600);
    }

    if(is_iOS8)
    {
        // Doesn't Work
        // self.view.superview.bounds = newSize;

        // Doesn't seem to do anything either.
        self.preferredContentSize = newSize.size;
    }
    else
    {
        // Works a treat on ios7
        self.view.superview.bounds = newSize;
    }

    self.minimised = !self.minimised;
}

- (IBAction)closeTouched:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for noting the `preferredContentSize` setting; in my case that was good enough.

Comment: Glad to hear it.. you only seem to need to go through the extra faff if you want to resize the view after you've opened it and set the original size.. i.e. make it grow from 300x300 to 600x600 when you press a button for example. 

I opened a ticket with Apple developer support and in the end they suggested i raise it was a bug.. but the solution below appears to be a work around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much messing around.. if you update the view.superview's bounds to something and then call layoutIfNeeded on the superview. This will cause the willLayoutSubviews method to be invoked. If you set the superview bounds in there, it will update the modal dialog size but not if you do it anywhere else.

Example view controller solution:

```
#import "ModalWindowViewController.h"

@interface ModalWindowViewController ()
@property bool minimised;
@property CGRect windowBounds;
@end

#define is_iOS8 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]floatValue] >= 8)

@implementation ModalWindowViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Start with a minimised window size.
    self.minimised = YES;
    self.windowBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);

    if(is_iOS8)
    {
        // Set initial size in iOS 8 etc.
        self.preferredContentSize = self.windowBounds.size;
    }
}

- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    // Resize the window based on it's current required size.
    // The supeview bounds only seems to actually changed on screen
    // if changed inside this method.
    self.view.superview.bounds = self.windowBounds;
}

- (IBAction)minMaxTouched:(id)sender
{
    // Toggle the dimensions of the window bases on minimised / maximised state.
    if (self.minimised == YES)
    {
        self.windowBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 600);
    }
    else
    {
        self.windowBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
    }

    // Set some value that will get overridden in viewWillLayoutSubviews
    // You need to change the view bounds or it won't actually invoke a layout.
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

    // Toggle minimised state before we layout.
    self.minimised = !self.minimised;

    // Manually request a layout. Since the superview bounds have been changed
    // to a temporary value it should cause a layout where we set the real
    // desired size.
    [self.view.superview layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (IBAction)closeTouched:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```